# Differentiate $f(x)=\tanh(x)$

Tags: calculus, analysis, functions, derivatives

> Calculate the first derivative of the function $f:=
> \tanh=\frac{\sinh}{\cosh}: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$

I know that $\sinh(x)=\frac{1}{2}(e^{x} -e^{-x})$ and $\cosh(x) = \frac{1}{2}(e^{x}+e^{-x})$

$\Rightarrow$

$$f(x)=\frac{e^{x}-e^{-x}}{e^{x}+e^{-x}}$$

$$f'(x)= \frac{(e^{x}+e^{-x})(e^{x}+e^{-x})-((e^{x}-e^{-x})(e^{x}-e^{-x}))}{(e^{x}+e^{-x})^{2}}$$

$$f'(x)=1-\frac{(e^{x}-e^{-x})^{2}}{(e^{x}+e^{-x})^{2}}$$

$$f'(x)=1-\left(\frac{e^{x}-e^{-x}}{e^{x}+e^{-x}}\right)^{2}$$

$$f'(x)=1-\left(\frac{\sinh(x)}{\cosh(x)}\right)^{2}$$

$$f'(x)=1-\tanh^{2}(x)$$

---

Is everything right? The calculation, the form etc.?

Comment: This seems correct to me. Perhaps an easier way to do this is to know that $\sinh' = \cosh$ and $\cosh' = \sinh$ so that $\tanh' = (\cosh\cdot \cosh - \sinh\cdot \sinh)/\cosh^2 = 1-\tanh^2$

Comment: You can further simplify it to $\text{sech}^2 x$.

Comment: A better alternative to "It looks good" is "what step are you unsure of?" (Did some editing BTW)

Comment: I was especially not sure if I did the forming after the fraction trick correctly. Also about the form, maybe the form is wrong, for example missing equivalence symbols or something like that. But if you say it's fine I'm happy because I would do it like that in the exam :-) In addition I thought, maybe there are much easier and faster solutions than this one someone could tell me.

Comment: @tenepolis I would prefer to see $f'(x)=...=...=...=1-\tanh^2(x)$ instead of lots of new lines starting with $f'(x)=...$.

Comment: Oh alright. What I always wanted know but for somewhat reason never asked, does it make a difference / is it wrong if you write the "=" in the next line? Or it has all to be in one and the same line? If I write in the next line, do I have to use a "=" at the end of the line and another "=" at the beginning of the new line? I hope I didn't ask too unclear / confusing.

Comment: There are different schools for that. In English literature it is common to break a line *before* the equality sign and to start a new line with it. I am used to double the sign *before* and *after* the line break. Both styles are correct, but do not mix them in the same text.

Answer (score 1):

From you formula
$$f'(x)=\frac{(e^x+e^{-x})^2-(e^x-e^{-x})^2}{(e^x+e^{-x})^2}$$
$$=\frac{4}{(e^x+e^{-x})^2}$$
$$=\frac{1}{\cosh^2 x}=sech^2 x$$